# PHP insert generated arrays to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Let's say I have 5 arrays generated like so:

```
$MyArr = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++){
        $data[] = array(
        'title'        => 'Title',
        'description'        => 'Description',
        'created_on'    => 'Time'
        );
    }
```

How can I insert each iteration of the generated array into my `MySQL` database **table**?

UPD. I'm using `mysqli_connect();` function to connect to my database (I've followed tutorial on W3Schools website (Procedural).

Comment: Depends on your database connection - PDO, mysqli, mysql, some framework?

Comment: I've updated question. I'm using [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) tutorial to setup connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just loop through your data array like this:

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$yourData = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
    $yourData[] = array(
    'title'        => md5(rand()),
    'description'        => rand(0, 1)?'active':'banned',
    'created_on'    => rand(0, 1)?'now':'2014/12/31 14:51:52'
    );
}

for($j = 0; $j < count($yourData); $j++) {
    $title = $yourData[$j]["title"];
    $description = $yourData[$j]["description"];
    $created_on = $yourData[$j]["created_on"];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO yourTable (title,description,created_on) VALUES ($title, $description, $created_on)";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This has helped me a lot!

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: thats a bad idea, running insert 5 times when you only need to it once

Comment: also 2 loops is bad, and you close the connection in the loop so it will only ever insert one row

Comment: Actually, yes, I've implemented some fixes in your code, but mr. zachu gave me the right idea to work with.

Comment: That was written quickly just to give you an idea how it can be done. I agree it could be done better but it was midnight already :P